# Why optional is not giving warning or asking for force unwraping?

Tags: swift, option-type, forceunwrap

```
struct SomeStruct {
    var optVar : String?
    var nonOptVar : String = "Hello"
    var optvar2 : String!
}

let obj2 = SomeStruct(optVar: "a", nonOptVar: "b", optvar2: "c")
let a = obj2.optVar // why it is not asking for force unwraping
let b = obj2.nonOptVar
let c = obj2.optvar2
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
```

Please share your view on this. But while I use optionals in project generally it gives warling
'Expression implicitly coerced from String? to Any'

Comment: You'll only get the force unwrapping if the obj2 is optional.

Comment: Because `let` is a constant and can be not be assigned again. So compiler is making sure that `optVar` surely has some value. If you will take `a` as optional warning will not be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is mainly due to *type inference*. Here:

```
let a = obj2.optVar
```

`a` is inferred to be of type `String?`, because that's the type of the expression on the right, isn't it?

```
// basically this:
let a: Optional<String> = obj2.optVar
```

An optional value can be assigned to a variable of an optional type. Nothing wrong with that.

If you declare `a` to be of type `String`, however, you need to unwrap it:

```
let a: String = obj2.optVar // error!
```

The warning `'Expression implicitly coerced from String? to Any'` appears when you are trying to put an optional value into a variable of type `Any`, like this:

```
let a: Any = obj2.optVar // warning!
```

Comment: +1, maybe it will be the good point to show it can be assign also `Optional` type like `let anyOptional: Optional = obj2.optVar`